# reuse parameters defined within config.parmeters file in java

Tags: java, selenium

I have a config properties file in a java project created in eclipse.

Below are the contents in the properties file.

```
adminApp= testAdminDemo
customerApp = testCustDemo
appHostIP = 172.22.XX.XX
adminAppURL = http://appHostIP:9049/adminApp
customerAppURL = http://appHostIP:9049/customerApp
```

When the appURL parameter is read from a Java class,

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\config.properties");
            prop.load(f);
            String url = prop.getProperty("appURL");
System.out.println("URL: " + url);
```

the output is the same value mentioned for parameter 'url' in config.parameters file:

```
http://appHostIP:9049/adminApp
```

Actually, I expected the output to be like:

```
http://172.22.XX.XX:9049/testAdminDemo
```

Is there anything wrong in this approach?

I don't want to read host ip and app name in the java class file and then form a string. Instead, the required URl should get formed in the properties file as need to deal with different apps - admin, customer, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform concatination in the property file, You have to handle the concatination in code where you are using it like below.

```
appHostIP = 172.22.XX.XX
adminAppURL = :9049/adminApp

String url = "http://" + "prop.getProperty("appHostIP")+ prop.getProperty("appURL");
```